# 0 page faults with infinite RAM

Tags: architecture, operating-system, paging, ram

Page faults only happen when a memory is not loaded into RAM and is actually in secondary storage? i.e. virtual address is not a physical address and the page table has an invalid bit.

However, what if we had a large pool of RAM? For example infinite?

Does this mean there is no chance of a page fault occurring in our system because all possible needed memory will be in RAM?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean there is no chance of a page fault occurring in our system because all possible needed memory will be in RAM?

Not at all. On most systems a page does not get mapped to physical memory until it is actually accessed. That is why you get many page faults when a program starts up. These page faults occur even when memory is avaialble.